# BindableAttribute, Combobox, Selectedvalue property - WinForms

Tags: bindable-linq

I am deriving from combobox (WinForms) and am providing a new implementation for the Selectedvalue property.

It works fine as is, but any change to the selectedvalue property is not updating other controls bound to the same "binding context" to change their values accordingly.

I did try adding the BindableAttribute(true) to the property, but still it does nottrigger the change in value to the other linked controls.

The control's DataBindings.add(...) is all set up. And other controls are also bound to the same data filed on the same datasource.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you called your base class' implementation of overridden methods?  It's possible that failing to call the base class implementation is accidentally circumventing the code that fires various event plumbing.